# Vertical align content with float element + responsive layout

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position, vertical-alignment

i have a component box layout with an image on left/right + content needs to be vertical align middle. And it needs to be work responsive to mobile in a layout of image on top + content at bottom. [Click Here for Jsfiddle Attempt: 1 Code Link](http://jsfiddle.net/BmZs4/1/)

i've tried with **.wrapper** display *table* and **.img-wrap, .content-wrap** display *table-cell* works fine on desktop but when it comes to mobile each component box must have image on top, and content below. [Click here for Jsfiddle Attempt: 2 code Link](http://jsfiddle.net/GXP6t/1/)

My desire outcome was to get the result of attempt 2 (for desktop) and attempt 1 (for mobile). Preferably the same html layout for both if possible - Attempt 1 HTML.

> #### Update:
>
> I've tried with a different approach (link as below) that i've found from [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) at fist i thought it does center vertically but then after i start adding more text content it doesn't works anymore. Does anyone know why?
>
> [Click here for Jsfiddle Attempt: 3 code Link](http://jsfiddle.net/BmZs4/11/)

#### HTML - Attempt 3

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="img-wrap left">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="content-wrap">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. ... Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
    </div></p>
    </div></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="img-wrap right">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="content-wrap">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS- Attempt 3

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper:before, .wrapper:after {
    display: table;
    content:'';
}
.wrapper:after {
    clear:both;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
    position :relative;
    max-width: 800px;
    display:block;
    margin: 30px auto;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    *zoom:1;
}
.wrapper:before {
    content:'';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.img-wrap {
    width:30%;
}
.left {
    float:left;
}
.right {
    float: right;
}
.img-wrap img {
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
}
.content-wrap {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    padding:20px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    position: relative;
}
.content-wrap:before {
    content:'';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
    .right, .left {
        float:none;
    }
    .wrapper:before {
        display: none;
    }
    .img-wrap {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .content-wrap {
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use `display:table` to achieve `vertical-align`:

**css**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper:before, .wrapper:after {
    display: table;
    content:'';
}
.wrapper:after {
    clear:both;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
    position :relative;
    max-width: 800px;
    display:table;
    margin: 30px auto;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    vertical-align:middle;
    *zoom:1;
}
.img-wrap {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: left;
}
.left {
    float:left;
}
.right {
    float: right;
}
.img-wrap img {
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
}
.content-wrap {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    padding:20px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    position:relative;
}
@media screen and (max-width:750px) {
    .right, .left {
        float:none;
    }
    .img-wrap {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .content-wrap {
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BmZs4/3/)

Comment: There are two different layout with different image positioning needs to achieve as mentioned earlier. And Image needs to be on top always on mobile view and content goes below it. Your suggested solution was very similar to what i've presented above (attempt 2) but that's not what i want, sorry.